# How do restore an existing repository using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn

After my OS crashed, I've installed a fresh version (Windows 7 Pro x64).

I want to commit my project changes, so I need to restore my local repository to do this. Of course I have the all files located in my folder where was the repository before the OS crash, but of course TortoiseSVN doesn't know that there was a repository. How can I do it (I believe it is possible to restore that repository)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you still have your repository folder, intact with all the .svn subfolders, all you should need is installing TortoiseSVN itself after the OS reinstall. TortoiseSVN does not rely on anything outside the file system to identify working folders, so you should be able to just check in.

Comment: You're right, the only difference is there is not that green circled icon on the folder icon

Comment: TSVN icon cache may not be caught up. If you right-click the folder, do you have the TSVN check-in submenu?

Comment: Also, see @Tobias answer regarding the "upgrade working-copy" function.

Comment: If I click PPM on that folder I have 3 options: SVN Update, SVN Commit and the TortoiseSVN submenu. So, that folder is treated as a normal working copy folder

Comment: So isn't that what you are after?

Comment: What if I have the inverse problem, I have a local working copy, but have lost the repository ? I get I can't get the changes back, but would like to re-establish what I can using the data in the working copies .svn folder. (Hopefully there's some changelog in there)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mixing up "repository" and "working-copy" here.

Assuming you have a local repository created on your harddrive:

To find your repository you could do a fresh checkout of your local repository and specify the location starting with "file://". If you have an old working-copy, but the repository is not at its old location, you can relocate it with the TortoiseSVN command "relocate".

An old working-copy should just show up. Chances are that it doesn't show up, because you installed a new version of TortoiseSVN (1.7.x) which uses a newer working-copy-format that is different from the older format. You need to select your working-copy directory and select "upgrade working-copy" so you can work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply checkout a new project and copy the .svn folder into existing project.