# TortoiseSVN items not found in Context menu

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My PC was formatted and I have re-installed tortoiseSVN but SVN items(commit, update, etc) are not available in context menu. I have tried many options mentioned in web forums including re-installing, registry edits but the problem still exists. What could be the reason? Please share some experiences.

Please note that my current tortoiseSVN version is 1.8.7 and .svn folder also available in SVN linked folders.

Comment: in regedit, check HKCR\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN
Is it there? If not, it didn't install correctly.

Comment: also...have you rebooted?

Comment: Hi Garr, Thank you for the response. Yes it is available in HKCR and I have tried deleting default key and proceed with Repair in the installation as well. Reboot also performed several times. Can this be a version problem?

Comment: if you right-click on a folder that doesn't have a .svn subfolder, do you get the "SVN Checkout..." option? If so, then the problem is your local copy isn't recognized.

Comment: Yeah Garr, SVN Checkout is available in that case. So how can I fix this?

Comment: do you have changes you haven't committed? Easiest is probably to checkout project again to a new folder.

Comment: why not install latest version of TortoiseSVN? I think that might be the issue, if the working directory is in a newer format.

Comment: http://corylearning.blogspot.com/2012/10/tortoisesvn-doesnt-recognize-projects.html

Comment: This even looks like a dup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541770/how-do-restore-an-existing-repository-using-tortoisesvn

Comment: Dear Garr, Got the problem sorted by installing TortoiseSVN 1.7.7. Probably my working directory is in an older format. Since I have some uncommitted changes I can't checkout again. Anyway thanks for the guidance given.